# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare happening on same line

Tags: php, wordpress, function, buddypress, redeclaration

I have been fighting with this error for a while. The error is somewhere in the function I now have php telling me it can't redeclare a variable on the same line... strange. Any help would be great.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
>   bp_block_admin_init() (previously
>   declared in
>   /home/bp-member-login-redirect/bp-member-login-redirect-loader.php:31)
>   in
>   /home/bp-member-login-redirect/bp-member-login-redirect-loader.php
>   on line 31

lines 29-31

```
// make sure buddypress is installed
function bp_block_admin_init() {
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/bp-member-login-redirect-core.php' );
}
```

the lines actually calling the function (i get the error with or without these lines in the code:

```
if ( defined( 'BP_VERSION' ) ) {
    bp_block_admin_init();
} else {
    add_action( 'bp_init', 'bp_block_admin_init' );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP can only tell you where the function is attempting to be defined. It has nothing to do with code that executes that function, which is why removing the code that calls that function has no effect. Please post the rest of the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with the WordPress function `register_activation_hook()` which is called when a plugin is loaded. In my case, the file was being included without WordPress loading. Once I removed the functions I no longer got an error.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you use require_once to ensure you're not double loading the bp-member-login-redirect-loader.php file.

```
require_once '/home/bp-member-login-redirect/bp-member-login-redirect-loader.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `bp_block_admin_init` is being defined twice.  In what file does this code appear?  Is another file `require`-ing or `include`-ing this file multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're including `bp-member-login-redirect-loader.php` more than once. For example, the following is sufficient to reproduce your problem:

#### test.php

```
<?php
function foo() {}
?>
```

#### test2.php

```
<?php
include('test.php');
include('test.php'); // Double definition of foo() on test.php:2
?>
```

Comment: That's totally what's happening I just don't see where as I'm not including the file more than once unless I'm missing something..

Answer (score 1):

Please check it whether the function `bp_block_admin_init()` is already exists or not.

```
if(!function_exists('bp_block_admin_init'){
  function bp_block_admin_init(){
    //....
  }
}
```